# Prevent ToolStripMenuItem context menu from closing on click

Tags: winforms, events, c#-4.0, controls, contextmenu

I'm trying to have my context menu stay on screen even after I click one of its dropdown items (when the shift key is pressed, though I don't think that matters to the issue).  You can see an example of the behavior in Windows XP when you click on Start > All Programs > Accessories > [now hit your shift key] and click on Windows Explorer... The menu stays up.

It's a C# app, using Winforms, development machine is Windows 7, production is either XP, Vista or 7.

The toolstripmenuitem doesn't seem to have a `closing` event; only a `closed` one.  Those familiar with a `closing` event will know that you can set a `cancel` flag to prevent the control from closing.

Also, when I try a workaround of remaking it visible from within either its `click` event or its `closed` event, it doesn't work.  Although that would have been a tolerable workaround in the immediate, it is not for production.

Any suggestions or related info greately appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: MORE INFO: The menu that I want to prevent closing is 2 levels down from the context menu and is built dynamically. Only the parentmost contextmenu has a closing event and if I cancel the closing in that event the behavior seems to be that the context menu stays up, one level down also stays up but the last, 3rd level closes nonetheless.  At this point I've started to play around with the autoclose property set to false of the last level and although that seems to work it has other nasty side effects of other events no longer firing when setting autoclose back to true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to have a dynamically created submenu of my ContextMenu stay on screen upon being clicked by setting the AutoClose property of its Parent DropDown menu to "False" like this:

```
ParentMenu.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
```

where ParentMenu is a `ToolStripMenuItem`.

The use of the Closing event of the DropDown's Parent `ToolStripDropDownMenu` to acheive this by setting a "Cancel" flag was not a viable solution because it caused inconsistant showing/hiding behavior in either of its 2 levels of Parent menus as well as causing unexpected visual artifacts on screen that I could not get rid of when later being hidden through code.  It also seemed to cause certain events of the dynamically created menu's Parents to no longer fire, such as its `MouseEnter` event.

An interesting find during this experience was that although Visual Studio 2010's intellisense lists a `LostFocus` event for a `DropDown` of a context menu item; when adding this event to dynamically created menus it does not get fired; this is apparently a known behavior as mentionned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b8f9cf48-9bd4-4e8e-a9b7-bedc7491c619/):

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I ended up using.  With this method, the dropdown's autoclose is only disabled while the mouse pointer is on the drop down control. `MyMenuItem` is type `ToolStripMenuItem`.

```
AddHandler MyMenuItem.DropDown.MouseEnter, AddressOf DisableDropMenuClose
AddHandler MyMenuItem.DropDown.MouseLeave, AddressOf EnableDropMenuClose

Private Sub DisableDropMenuClose(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    CType(sender, ToolStripDropDownMenu).AutoClose = False
End Sub

Private Sub EnableDropMenuClose(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    CType(sender, ToolStripDropDownMenu).AutoClose = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. I renamed my methods to MyDropDown_MouseEnter and MyDropDown_MouseLeave. This way, the method does not appear to be tied to one piece of functionality.

Answer (score 4):

The ToolStripDropDownMenu has the Closing event.

```
private void MyContextMenuStrip_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anders.  I read your comment yesterday and I've been poking around with that and a few other ideas but a solution has not come of it yet.