# How to Leave ToolStripMenu Open After Clicking an Item

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, menu, menuitem

I'm creating a `ToolStripMenu` shown below that is supposed to allow the user to interact with the items "XML" and "Non XML" as though they are regular check boxes on a form. However, when one item is checked/unchecked the menu closes. How can I allow an item to be checked/unchecked without closing the menu? Or is there a different standard method of achieving the same behavior?

[image]

So what I want is to be able to click on "Non XML", show a check box and leave the menu open.
The idea is that the last menu item will be "Done" and when it's clicked the "G2S" sub items will remain open but the "Display" sub items ( XML, Non XML ) will close.

Any ideas?

**Note: I am aware that this is likely not the best user interface design. I'd like to know however how this could be accomplished just to gain some technical knowledge about handling menus.**

Comment: This sounds like a horrible user experience, simply because it goes against the concept of a menu. Perhaps you should re-think how to display this option.

Comment: I agree with Kendall. A modal form where they can make all choices at once then hit a "Proceed button" would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Well I suppose clicking on "Display" could pop up a small dialog. But what if I really wanted to create the user experience described above?

Comment: @Chimera Go ahead, but don't expect me to help you design something that I myself would avoid.

Comment: @KendallFrey Ok, thanks for the advice. I'll most likely redesign my user interface. But I'm kind of interested in the way my design can be implemented just to gain a better understanding of things.

Comment: I'd imagine that you'd have to hack apart the ToolStripMenu object to keep it from closing after the initial item is selected. It will most likely get ugly REALLY fast, and be more of a headache than you'd want.

Plus, you should follow pre-existing conventions on how the UI experience should go. For the same reasons why so many people say "Don't over-ride Alt-F4 to open a new Form", your users expect the forms to behave a certain way. You shouldn't change from that, unless you have an absolute reason to do so. I don't think anything you've mentioned so far would qualify.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Just as a regression, I remembering coming to Windows from the Amiga world and found it very annoying that the menus closed after a click (with check-box settings). I guess concept of menu means different things based on what you're used to - which also makes it "dangerous" to change, but better solutions has always come out from people that dared to be bold. Generally speaking :-)

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware Agreed! I gotta believe there is some way to do what I'm looking for. Even if not everybody believes it's a good user interface.

Comment: I don't think it is such a bad idea.  I am using to allow checking sub nodes of a treeview node where I don't want to use checkboxes. I would use checkboxes if I could enable them for just the leaf nodes, but that does not appear to be possible.

Comment: Disagree with @KendallFrey. I really like the UX of Visual Studio when choosing visible buttons of its toolbars.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting concept is described in [this thread on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826183/prevent-toolstripmenuitem-context-menu-from-unloading-on-click):

Here is the essence of the accepted answer:

```
ParentMenu.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
```

It does exactly what you are asking for - prevent menu from closing when subitem is clicked.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I'm off to try it out.

Comment: Thank you Neolisk.  You might also want to add:
    ParentMenu.AutoClose = false;
Otherwise the dropdown  will hang out there by itself.   This is valid but I didn't like the visual effect in my application.

Comment: @MarkAinsworth: Then maybe also traverse all the way to the parent, in case you have multiple levels of menu nesting? I will leave this as an exercise for visitors. Thanks for a note though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a useful extension that requires user to click outside of menu item + dropdowns to close.

```
    public static void KeepOpenOnDropdownCheck (this ToolStripMenuItem ctl)
    {
        foreach (var item in ctl.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
        {
            item.MouseEnter += (o, e) => ctl.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
            item.MouseLeave += (o, e) => ctl.DropDown.AutoClose = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Posted in case somebody finds it helpful.**

Instead of trying to do exactly what I had originally intended, I've come up with the following:

1- Use a `ContextMenuStrip` 
2- When the user clicks on the `ToolStripMenu` item I display the `ContextMenuStrip` at a location near the menu item as shown below: ( note the positioning still needs adjusting )

[image]

To get this working I build the `ContextMenuStrip` in code at run-time so that the items in the `ContextMenuStrip` can be build dynamically based on the situation.

Code snippets:

Show the `ContextMenuStrip` when the menu item is clicked:

```
private void filterToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Show(this, 180, 20);
}
```

Build the `ContextMenuStrip`:

```
    if (protInfo.Name == "QCOM" )
    {
        BroadCast = new CheckBox();
        BroadCast.Text = "Date/Time Broadcast";
        BroadCast.Checked = FlagSet(CurrentFilter, (Byte)Filter.DateTimeBC);
        ToolStripControlHost Ch1 = new ToolStripControlHost(BroadCast);

        GenPoll = new CheckBox();
        GenPoll.Text = "Status Poll";
        GenPoll.Checked = FlagSet(CurrentFilter, (Byte)Filter.GenStatusPoll);
        ToolStripControlHost Ch2 = new ToolStripControlHost(GenPoll);

        GenPollResp = new CheckBox();
        GenPollResp.Text = "Status Poll Response";
        GenPollResp.Checked = FlagSet(CurrentFilter, (Byte)Filter.GenStatusResponse);
        ToolStripControlHost Ch3 = new ToolStripControlHost(GenPollResp);

        Button btnDone = new Button();
        btnDone.Text = "Done";
        ToolStripControlHost Ch4 = new ToolStripControlHost(btnDone);
        btnDone.Click += new EventHandler(btnDone_Click);

        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(Ch1);
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(Ch2);
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(Ch3);
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(Ch4);
        contextMenuStrip1.Enabled = true;
        filterToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        filterToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    }
```

This may not be the best user interface design, but it seems to work.

Comment: Upvoted for showing how to add a button (or other control) to a menu.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The original solution will work with the use of mouse events.

On mouse enter event:

parent.dropdown.autoclose = false;

on mouse leave event:

parent.dropdown.autoclose = true;

The only catch is if the user access the menu items by other means than a mouse.

Comment: Nice solution - tried a few - this is the best.

Answer (score 1):

I used a combination of Neolisk's and Chimera's answers to allow deletion of multiple leaf items from a treeview.  My solution is below

Note: the following Items created at design time are used:
  TreePromotions (TreeView)
  menuVendorSection (Context Menu Strip)
  removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem (DropDown of menuVendorSection)

```
 private void removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear();  
        ToolStripMenuItem detailMenuItem;
        TreeNode vendorSectionNode = treePromotions.SelectedNode;
        for (int vsn = 0; vsn < vendorSectionNode.Nodes.Count; vsn++)
        {
            //add checkbox item
            detailMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(vendorSectionNode.Nodes[vsn].Text);
            detailMenuItem.Tag = vendorSectionNode.Nodes[vsn].Tag;
            detailMenuItem.CheckOnClick = true;
            removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(detailMenuItem);

        }
        //add action buttons
        Button buttonDeleteMultiple = new Button();
        buttonDeleteMultiple.Text = "Remove Checked Items";
        ToolStripControlHost buttonHost = new ToolStripControlHost(buttonDeleteMultiple);
        buttonDeleteMultiple.Click += new EventHandler(buttonDeleteMultiple_Click);
        removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(buttonHost);

        Button buttonCancelMultipleDelete = new Button();
        buttonCancelMultipleDelete.Text = "CANCEL";
        buttonHost = new ToolStripControlHost(buttonCancelMultipleDelete);
        buttonCancelMultipleDelete.Click += new EventHandler(buttonCancelMultipleDelete_Click);
        removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(buttonHost);



        removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
        menuVendorSection.AutoClose = false;





    }

    private void buttonDeleteMultiple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //delete items
        for (int dmi = 0; dmi < removeAllItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count - 2; dmi++) //do not include buttons
        {
            ((Detail)removeAllItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[dmi].Tag).Delete(); //deletes item from database
        }
        //rebuild leaf
        treePromotions.SelectedNode.Nodes.Clear();
        addItemNodes(treePromotions.SelectedNode);  //builds leaf nodes from database

        //close menus
        removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Close();
        menuVendorSection.AutoClose = true;
        menuVendorSection.Close();
    }

    private void buttonCancelMultipleDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //just close menus
        removeMultipleItemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Close();
        menuVendorSection.AutoClose = true;
        menuVendorSection.Close();
    }
```

[image: And here is what it looks like]

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still interested, here is a vb solution:

1) For the parent tool strip menu item, add the following handler in the form's constructor:

```
AddHandler ParentTSMI.DropDown.Closing, AddressOf onDropDownClosing
```

2) The handler:

```
Private Sub onDropDownClosing(sender As Object, e As ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs)
    If e.CloseReason = ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

That's it all.

Don't forget to remove the handler (RemoveHandler) when you close the form.